# Could not create swift NSViewController class in xcode 6

Tags: swift, xcode6, nsviewcontroller

While creating a subclass of NSViewController in Xcode 6 GM seed I cant select the language as swift. Screenshot attached.Anyone experienced problem like this? Why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Exactly what version of Xcode are you using? Bear in mind that you'll need the 6.1 beta to develop with Swift for OS X...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release version of Xcode 6.0 doesn't support Swift on OS X. From the [Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=14):

> Today is the GM date for Swift on iOS. We have one more GM date to go for Mac. Swift for OS X currently requires the SDK for OS X Yosemite, and when Yosemite ships later this fall, Swift will also be GM on the Mac. In the meantime, you can keep developing your Mac apps with Swift by downloading the beta of Xcode 6.1.

So at the moment, to use NSViewController in Swift (as it's a Mac UI class, as opposed to iOS's UIViewController) you'd need to [download](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) the latest 6.1 beta release. The final release version of Xcode 6.0, which you're using, only supports iOS development.